# How to get all pages from a site collection with a specific criteria with powershell

Tags: powershell

I have the following code and it seems it works fine, but it only returns things from the root site.
We have like 200 subsites, and the script should return all pages where the contacts field on the page is not null

```
Get-SPWeb "https://xxxxx.com" |
   Select -ExpandProperty Lists |
   Where { $_.GetType().Name -eq "SPDocumentLibrary" -and
           -not $_.Hidden } |
   Select -ExpandProperty Items |
   Where { $_["Contacts"] -ne $null } |
   Select Name, {$_.File.Author}, url, {$_["Contacts"] }
```

Comment: What SharePoint version are you trying to query this information from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passed a URL, Get-SPWeb only returns the SPWeb object for the specific site you list. To get all the sites and subsites in a site collection, pipe the SPSite object to Get-SPWeb like so:

```
Get-SPSite "http://whatever...." | Get-SPWeb -Limit All
```